# Redux actions vs redux-saga actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am kind of in dilemma when do we need to use redux actions and redux saga actions.

I don't mean to ask when to use redux and when to use redux-saga. But I would like to know that what scenario do we need to use redux actions when we use redux saga. Or don't I need to use redux actions when using redux saga?

Please help me understanding the use cases of redux when using redux-saga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but just in case: the actions themselves are indistinguishable between redux and redux-saga. In both cases, an action is an object with a type, and possibly a payload. For example, this is an action:

```
{
  type: 'DO_STUFF',
  value: 3,
}
```

When you dispatch an action, it's first going to go into your middlewares. Redux-saga is an example of a middleware, and it can decide whether it wants to do anything with the action. If the action gets past redux-saga, it then goes to the reducers.

So i believe what you're asking is: when should you handle an action with a saga, and when should you handle it with a reducer. The answer to that comes down to the reason redux-saga and similar middleware were created in the first place:

**Reducers are always synchronous pure functions.**

So you'll use a saga when you want to do something asynchronous and/or impure. The asynchronous part of that is the thing that comes up most often. If you want to fetch data, it will be in a saga. If you want to set up an interval to do something over time, it will be in a saga.

On rare occasions you might have something that's synchronous, but impure, and that might also be something you put in a saga. One recent example i had was that i wanted to dispatch an action, and rather than updating the application state, i wanted it to save something to local storage. This happens synchronously, but since it's a side effect it's better for me to put it in a saga.

---

As requested in the comments, a clarification about synchronous but impure. A function is synchronous if it does all its work before it returns. A function is pure if it 1) has no side effects and 2) for a given input, it always returns the same output.

A side effect is when a function changes something external to itself, but by a means other than its return value. With a pure function, i should be able to call it and assume that nothing has changed outside of that function. For example:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', 'hello world');
doSomething();
console.log(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

If i know nothing about `doSomething` except that it's pure, then i can be certain that `localStorage.getItem('data')` will return 'hello world'. But on the other hand if doSomething is impure, then i can't make that assumption. In principle, the value in local storage could have been changed, resulting in a different log statement.

So a function that modifies local storage, such as the following, is impure despite being synchronous:

```
const doSomething = (value) => {
  localStorage.setItem('data', value);
}
```

The second way something could be impure is if it doesn't always return the same thing for its same inputs. For example, the following function is synchronous but impure:

```
const getTime = () => {
  return Date.now();
}
```

If i call that multiple times, i will usually get different numbers each time.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. But I'm not clear with synchronous but impure. Can you please give an example? (To say; I'm not quite clear with last paragraph)

Comment: I've added in clarification about synchronous but impure.